# how do I hide footer of all view controller witch attach with my navigation controller in swift project?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift4, footer, xcode9

I am working on swift project, which uses Xcode 9 and swift 4.1. I created one navigation viewcontroller and then created other view controller and attached with that that navigation viewcontroller.

so I got header and footer by default.so I have a two problems,

1. Now I want a change a color of footer other than white but when I write any code for that It diminished behind footer and I don't see any color without white.How do I give any color to footer?
2. If I am not able to give color to footer so I want to hide that footer using bellow code

   ```
   override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
   {
      self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true
   }
   ```

But by this color I am able to hide only header not a footer. so how do I hide footer using code so I created customise footer what I want.

How do I solve above problem in swift 4.1?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what you mean by footer here because by default when you embed your viewcontroller inside navigation controller it doesn't show any footer.
There are two possible things that you are doing there:

1. Either your navigation controller is embedded inside TabBarController
2. Or you have unhidden the toolbar of navigation controller.

Now if you are using TabBarController as a parent of your navigation controller you can simply use following code to hide the footer:

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
```

If you are using navigation controller's toolbar (which is hidden by default). You can use following code for hiding it:

```
navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

and for changing the color of toolbar you can simply use:

```
navigationController?.toolbar.barTintColor = .black
```